# Ending of Half Light

Tags: ending, half-light

At the end of [Half Light (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412798/), Angus commits suicide by jumping from the top of the lighthouse. Is he the ghost Angus McCulloch, or the real person who pretended to be the ghost? I got a bit confused about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**From the wiki article on this movie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Light)

> the two spark a romance that suddenly goes awry when she learns that Angus died seven years ago by committing suicide after murdering his wife and her lover in the lighthouse.

...

> However, after a brief fight at the lighthouse, Sharon hits her head and is killed in the kitchen, and Brian is murdered by Patrick, possessed by the spirit of Angus, in much the same way that Angus's wife and lover died seven years previously. Patrick then jumps from the tower, as Angus had done.

Implying that Angus was dead but, although Patrick did pretend to be Angus for a time, Angus **did possess him to kill him** by making him jump as he did.